# Instock config product not showing up in frontend instead out of stock product shows up

Tags: product, configurable-product, frontend, simple-product

i have created a config product with 3 simple products associated to it.

Ex: Config product: Myproduct

Simple products: Myproduct 1, Myproduct 2, Myproduct 3

Myproduct 1 is set to instock and qty to 10 and other two simple products are out of stock. what i am seeing in frontend is Myproduct 2 which is actually out of stock and also i cannot see the add to cart button for this product which is showing Myproduct 2. I am getting this issue for this product only, for other config products everything is fine. So i really dont have any idea where to start this. please someone help me friends

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

In the configurable product check the inventory settings to show as the product is in stock as by the sounds of it it will be currently showing as out of stock

Comment: hi, curtisc thanks for aswering. i have tried what u said, but still i am having the issue